# Docker copy files to and mount same folder

Tags: docker, windows-7, docker-toolbox

I am working on 'tomcat:7.0.75-jre8-alpine' base image and want to deploy my web application alongwith its configurations file. Below is what I am doing in Dockerfile:

```
......
COPY <my-app-configurations> /org/app/data
COPY <my-app-configurations> /org/app/conf
......
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And I am using below command to create a container from above image:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -v "/c/Users/jaffy/app:/org/app" myapp-image
```

'/c/Users/jaffy/app' folder is initially empty and I want to get all contents of '/org/app' in it and remains in-sync.

Initially, all configurations are copied in '/org/app' folder but when '/c/Users/jaffy/app' is mounted, '/org/app' gets cleaned/emptied.

How can I solve this issue that host machine folder remains empty initially but afterwards it reflects the exact state of container's '/org/app' folder and its sub-directories.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to mount something at build time. Is this a special usecase? You can put your app and conf files in a folder you use as build context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep the container's folder content when you mount/share a volume over that folder, because the command is replacing the folder not merging it.

If you don't need to replace all the files in the folder you could just mount the file that need to be changed like:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -v "/c/Users/jaffy/app/web.xml:/org/app/web.xml" my-app-image
```